# Implementing smooth animation using handler and runnable

Tags: java, android, animation

I have implemented a custom view which is basically a flywheel. You can turn it scrolling with your finger. It was working fine until I tried to implement some kind of inertia on the flywheel when the touch is released. The problem is that, unlike when someone is scrolling the wheel, the inertia animation is laggy and jerky.

I found that the onFling method is of great help but as I compute the angular speed of the wheel in the onScroll method I did not find the need to override onFling. I have also found the Scroller API that gives you the positions you need when using inertia to play it into an Animation class.

As I want my app to be used for users below API 11, I cannot use the Animation class. So I came out with the solution of using a Runnable which moves my slider (the flywheel) according to the current angular speed, decreases the this speed and re run until the speed is below a certain value.
The Runnable is launched when having an onUp event and stopped when an onDown event is triggered.

```
public static final double REFRESH_RATE = 20.;
public static final double MIN_SPEED = 0.005;
private static final Handler mInertiaHandler = new Handler();
private final Runnable mInertiaRunnable = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      if(Math.abs(mAngularSpeed) > MIN_SPEED) {
         mAngleIter = mAngularSpeed *= 0.95;
         moveSlider();
         mInertiaHandler.postDelayed(this, (long) REFRESH_RATE);
      }
   }
};
```

As far as I understood, the problem lies in the invalidate() method, called inside moveSlider(), which is called too many times. Or that the process should wait that invalidate is over before recalling it. Here the runnable calls itself every 20 milliseconds. I tried to change this value without any more success.

Is there a way to implement properly an animation with a handler, or should I change to something else like an ASyncTask ?

Answer (score 1):

Using your way, i think it's hard to say - you are right, or not.

Inertia animation in android achieved through the use of interpolation.

Handler in Android is a tool which processing UI messages. But, no defenition around how fast it will be worked. May be you will have 30 FPS, and maybe you will have 100 FPS or 10 for awful performance.

**So i strongly not recommend to you use a Handler for your own animation.**

Android API have to you beautiful and easy framework to do this.

For inertia(of my past work i do same thing) you can use `ObjectAnimator` or\and `ValueAnimator`.

More information you can find in [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) guide.

Comment: So I should forget about implementing inertia for APIs under 11 ?

Comment: @DavidFournier no. Think simple.Inertia - it's just algorithm.  You can use it from version 1. Canvas is supported from begining.

Comment: @DavidFournier for worst case - you can change your layout properties as fast you can. You can implement a Thread which update your scrolling so quickly as can. For this action you need a postAtFrontOfQueue method in handler, with Thread.sleep.

Comment: @DavidFournier but i think devices with API<11 is not popular today.